# Robot Automation: Continue For Loop even if one test case fails

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework, testautomationfx

I have a robot test case as shown below:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Login Test
    ${jsonfile}    OperatingSystem.Get File   ${EXECDIR}/test/testData/LoginTestData.json
    ${source data}=    Evaluate     json.loads("""${jsonfile}""")    json
    ${all data members}=    Set Variable     ${source data['testcase']}
    FOR    ${member}    IN    @{all data members}
        Keyword 1   ${member} 
        Keyword 2   ${member} 
        .........
        Keyword n   ${member} 
   END
```

For any test data, if any keyword e.g 'Keyword 2' fails, I want to stop executing other keywords(e.g. Keyword 3 to Keyword n). But the loop should continue for other test data. How could I make this?

Answer (score 1):

Run each keyword inside `Run Keyword And Return Status` and if it's `False` call `Continue For Loop If` to start a new iteration:

```
        ${passed}=    Run Keyword And Return Status  Keyword 1   ${member}
        Continue For Loop If    not ${passed} 
        ${passed}=    Run Keyword And Return Status  Keyword 2   ${member}
        Continue For Loop If    not ${passed}
```

Comment: Hello Todor, Thank you for the response. Will it look good when there are many keywords?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Run Keyword ...` family. For example [Run Keyword And Continue On Failure](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Continue%20On%20Failure), or [Run Keyword And Ignore Error](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Ignore%20Error).I often use [Run Keyword And Return Status](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status) for these cases.